# Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor.executeScript(String, Object[])" because "jse" is null

Tags: java, appium-android

Any idea why I get NullPointerException here. Error - java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor.executeScript(String, Object[])" because "jse" is null

I am trying to input date (disabled field). Tests are running on Android.
This is a page object model framework with cucumber ,appium and Java.

```
**Base Class**

public AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver; 

public AppiumDriver<MobileElement> getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setDriver(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
public SignInPage getSignIn1() {

        return signInPage;
    }

    public SignUpPage getSignUpPage() {
        return signUpPage;
    }

    public AccountPage getAccountPage() {
        return accountPage;
    }

public void initializeObject(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        signInPage = new SignInPage(driver);
        signUpPage = new SignUpPage(driver);
        accountPage = new AccountPage(driver);

public void driverSetUp() throws Exception {
        
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        ConfigInfo config = ConfigInfo.instance();

if(config.platform.equals(platformName.ANDROID.name()) & (config.context.equals(context.ANDROIDWEB.name())))
        {
            cap.setCapability("deviceName", config.emulatorAndroidDeviceName);
            cap.setCapability("udid", config.emulatorAndroidUdid);
            cap.setCapability("platformName", config.emulatorAndroidPlatformName);
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"Chrome");
            cap.setCapability("platformVersion", config.emulatorAndroidPlatformVersion);
            cap.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable",config.chromeexecutables);       
            cap.setCapability("appium:chromeOptions", ImmutableMap.of("w3c", false));
            
            driver = new AndroidDriver<>(url, cap);         
            setDriver(driver);
            initializeObject(driver);
            driver.get(config.appURL);
            
        }

Sign up Class
public class SignUp {

    public AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    BaseSetUp baseSetUp;

    public SignUp(BaseSetUp baseSetUp) {
        this.baseSetUp = baseSetUp;

    }

@Then("I select the date from the calendar")
    public void i_select_the_date_from_the_calandar() throws Exception {
try {
                int[] currentDate = baseSetUp.currentDate();
                String date=currentDate[1]+"/"+currentDate[2]+"/"+currentDate[0];
                System.out.println(date);
                
                
                MobileElement element = baseSetUp.getSurveyPage().CalendarInput; // This is the date input field
                JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value('value', '" + date +"')", element);
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);

            }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `driver` is null. Put a breakpoint in your debugger and you can verify. You've also not showed where it's ever instantiated, either.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas of the Frozen Peas  Hi, Thank you. I have added more details. Can you please check?